# Elasticsearch: Using the results of a Metric Aggregation to filter the elements of a bucket and run additional aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-5

Given a dataset like

```
[{
    "type": "A",
    "value": 32
}, {
    "type": "A",
    "value": 34
}, {
    "type": "B",
    "value": 35
}]
```

I would like to perform the following aggregation:

- Firstly, I would like to group by "type" in buckets using the *terms*
  aggregation.
- After that, I would like to calculate some metrics of the field "value" using the *extended_stats*.
- Knowing the *std_deviation_bounds* (upper and lower) I would like to
  calculate the average value of the elements of the bucket excluding
  those outside the range [std_deviation_bounds.lower,
  std_deviation_bounds.upper]

First and second point of my list are trivial. I would like to know if the third point, using information of a sibling metric aggregation result to filter out elements of the bucket and recalculate an average is possible. And, if it is, I would like to have a hint of the aggregation structure I would need to use.

The version of the Elasticsearch instance is 5.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, OP here.

I still don't know if ElasticSearch allows to formulate an aggregation as I described in the original question.

What I did to solve this problem is taking a different approach. I will post it here just in case it is helpful to anyone else.

so,

```
POST hostname:9200/index/type/_search
```

with

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "group": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "type"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "histogramAgg": {
                    "histogram": {
                        "field": "value",
                        "interval": 10,
                        "offset": 0,
                        "order": {
                            "_key": "asc"
                        },
                        "keyed": true,
                        "min_doc_count": 0
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "statsAgg": {
                            "stats": {
                                "field": "value"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extStatsAgg": {
                    "extended_stats": {
                        "field": "value",
                        "sigma": 2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

will generate a result like this

```
{
    "took": 100,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 10,
        "successful": 10,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 100000,
        "max_score": 0.0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "group": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [{
                "key": "A",
                "doc_count": 10000,
                "histogramAgg": {
                    "buckets": {
                        "0.0": {
                            "key": 0.0,
                            "doc_count": 1234,
                            "statsAgg": {
                                "count": 1234,
                                "min": 0.0,
                                "max": 9.0,
                                "avg": 0.004974220783280196,
                                "sum": 7559.0
                            }
                        },
                        "10.0": {
                            "key": 10.0,
                            "doc_count": 4567,
                            "statsAgg": {
                                "count": 4567,
                                "min": 10.0,
                                "max": 19.0,
                                "avg": 15.544345993923,
                                "sum": 331846.0
                            }
                        },
                        [...]
                    }
                },
                "extStatsAgg": {
                    "count": 10000,
                    "min": 0.0,
                    "max": 104.0,
                    "avg": 16.855123857,
                    "sum": 399079395E10,
                    "sum_of_squares": 3.734838645273888E15,
                    "variance": 1.2690056384124432E9,
                    "std_deviation": 35.10540102369,
                    "std_deviation_bounds": {
                        "upper": 87.06592590438,
                        "lower": -54.35567819038
                    }
                }
            },
            [...]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If you pay attention to the results of the *group* aggregation for type:"A" you will notice we have now the average and the count of every sub-group of the histogram.
You will have noticed too the results of the *extStatsAgg* aggregation (sibling of the *histogram* aggregation) shows the *std_deviation_bounds* for every bucket group (for type:"A", type:"B",...)

As you may have noticed, this doesn't give the solution I was looking for. 
I needed to do a few calculations on my code. Example in pseudoCode

```
for bucket in buckets_groupAggregation

    Long totalCount = 0
    Double accumWeightedAverage = 0.0

    ExtendedStats extendedStats = bucket.extendedStatsAggregation
    Double upperLimit = extendedStats.std_deviation_bounds.upper
    Double lowerLimit = extendedStats.std_deviation_bounds.lower

    Histogram histogram = bucket.histogramAggregation
    for group in histogram

        Stats stats = group.statsAggregation

        if group.key > lowerLimit & group.key < upperLimit
            totalCount += group.count
            accumWeightedAverage += group.count * stats.average

    Double average = accumWeightedAverage / totalCount
```

Notes:
The size of the histogram interval will determine the "accuracy" of the final average. Finer interval will get more accurate results while increasing the aggregation time.

I hope it helps someone else